# Having trouble adding image in background for button in android

Tags: android, image, button, background

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4agpH.png)

I made a button and added the image in the background of the button but the image didn't pop up. In the video I followed the button's background changed but mine did not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `imageView` instead of `button` or remove

```
android:text=".."
```

to add an `imageview` which is recommended

```
<ImageView 
android:src = "@drawable/..."
android:scaleType = ""
```

by adding `scaletype` you will have alternative view and more control

Comment: so there's no why to add an image in the **button**'s background?

Comment: I'm trying to make a StateListDrawable. can I make StateListDrawable by imageview?